# Java - Record SWF stream from an URL

Tags: java, flash, record, capture

Every now and then there are some conferences that is being streamed over a specific URL as a SWF file.

I'd like to create a very small app where I can record hard-coded URL which is a streaming SWF file as MP4. I'd like to have both sound and video if available.

Would this be possible with JAVA?

I tried URLConnection and save with OutputStream but I can't open saved file with media player.

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: SWF is a compiled format rendered by a virtual machine (Adobe VM). It does not stream but such a file can have a/v bytes embedded within. **Question** Does your SWF display media controls? If YES then likely it's just a media player app that is loading external video data (MP4 or FLV). Find the MP4 source and use that in your Java app. Find means checking network logs while SWF app is running.

Comment: _"I can't open saved file with media player"_ share an example file for analysis of playback issues.